# How can i prevent a CWnd from getting the focus?

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc, focus

I write a MFC application and need a button which is not taling the input focus away from another window.

Removing the WS_TABSTOP style does unfortunately not help when the use clicks the button with the mouse. When i block WM_LBUTTONDOWN i don't get a visual pressed indication so this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a specific window you want to keep the focus, you could just force the focus back to your window using the `CWnd::SetFocus()` command in your button's `OnLButtonDown` handler.

If you want the focus restored to one of several windows, you could try subclassing CButton and trapping the `CWnd::OnSetFocus()` message which is sent when the keyboard focus changes to the button.

The `OnSetFocus()` event includes a CWnd of the control that just lost the focus, so you could manually put it back, either as part of the `OnSetFocus()` event itself, or later as part of the  `OnLButtonDown()` handler again.